# Use of integers and doubles give different answers when they shouldn't

Tags: java, math, integer, double, iteration

I'm solving a Project Euler [Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) using java. I am NOT asking for help solving the problem. I have already solved it, but I ran into something I can't figure out.

The problem is like this:

> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive
>   integers:
>
> n = n/2, if n is even
>   n = 3n + 1, if n is odd
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following
>   sequence:
>
> 13  -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1. Here, the length of the chain is 10 numbers.
>
> Find the starting number below 1,000,000 that produces the longest chain.

So I wrote this code:

```
public class Euler014 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int maxChainCount = 0;
        int answer = 0;
        int n;
        int chainCount = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
            n = i;
            while(n > 1){
                if(n%2 == 0){       //check if even
                    n /= 2;
                }else{              //else: odd
                    n = 3*n + 1;
                }
                chainCount++;
            }
            if(chainCount > maxChainCount){ //check if it's the longest chain so far
                maxChainCount = chainCount;
                answer = i;
            }
            chainCount = 1;
        }       
        System.out.println("\n\nLongest chain: i = " + answer);     
    }
}
```

This gives me the answer 910107, which is wrong.

HOWEVER, if i change the type of my n variable to `double n` it runs and gives me the answer 837799, which is right!

This really confuses me, as I can't see what the difference would be at all. I understand that if we use `int` and do divisions we can end up rounding numbers when we don't intend to. But in this case, we always check to see if the `n` is divisble by 2, BEFORE dividing by 2. So I thought that it would be totally safe to use integers. What am I not seeing?

This is the code in its entirety, copy, paste and run it if you'd like to see for yourself. It runs in a couple of seconds despite much iteration. =)

Comment: `int` is too small, that overflows for several values. Use `long`.

Comment: The first value you get `int` overflow for is `113383`, after 121 steps. `837799` overflows after 59 steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is overflow. If you change `int n` to `long n`, you'll get the right answer.

Remember: The numbers in the sequence can be ***really big***. So big they overflow `int`'s range. But not (in this case) `double`'s, or `long`'s.

At one point in the chain, `n` is `827,370,449` and you follow the `3n + 1` branch. That value wants to be `2,482,111,348`, but it overflows the capacity of `int` (which is `2,147,483,647` in the positive realm) and takes you to `-1,812,855,948`. And things go south from there. :-)

So your theory that you'd be fine with integer (I should say *integral*) numbers is correct. But they have to have the capacity for the task.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. Really explains in detail while keeping it simple and understandable. Thank you!