# Euler014 taking a lot longer with int than long

Tags: java, int

If I run the code below it takes less than 1 seconds to complete.

Bu if I change the sequence from long to int it takes more than 10 minutes.

Why?

```
long sequenceLength = 0;
long startingNumber = 0;
long sequence;

for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    int length = 1;
    sequence = i;
    while (sequence != 1) {
        if ((sequence % 2) == 0) {
            sequence = sequence / 2;
        } else {
            sequence = sequence * 3 + 1;
        }
        length++;
    }

    //Check if sequence is the best solution
    if (length > sequenceLength) {
        sequenceLength = length;
        startingNumber = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: See whether sequence goes out of range when it is int. You can find out this by printing it when it goes below zero

Comment: @PragalathanM: It does, when `sequence` reaches 827,370,449 and it follows the `sequence = sequence * 3 + 1` path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you've overflowing the `int` range, and so it's looping a **lot** more with `int`s than `long`s. See [my other answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225061/use-of-integers-and-doubles-give-different-answers-when-they-shouldnt/17225132#17225132) for a more detailed explanation of why Euler014 requires `long` on Java over the range you're using (which, coincidentally, is the range the other questioner was using).

Quoting from that answer with the updated variable name:

> At one point in the chain, `sequence` is `827,370,449` and you follow the `sequence = sequence * 3 + 1` branch. That value *wants* to be `2,482,111,348`, but it overflows the capacity of `int` (which is `2,147,483,647` in the positive realm) and takes you to `-1,812,855,948`.

And so you keep looping for a long time waiting for `sequence` to come back around to `1` in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

At a guess?  I suspect the overflow behavior is different.  If any intermediate result exceeds 2^31 - 1, then an `int` would overflow to a negative number, which would then have different results generally.